# Ansible and postgresql update functionality

Tags: database, postgresql, migration, ansible

Currently i'm working on my ansible playbook for postgresql database and i'd like to add following scenarios in case of installed old db version:

1 - if i have some flag to skip upgrade - ansible must keep old version installed

2 - if i have no flag or flag to upgrade - ansible should gently upgrade old version to the new one (for example - 9.2 to 9.4)  with suitable migration scripts.

What is the best way to do it? Any code examples?

Comment: What OS do you use? For example, if it's Ubuntu/Debian I'm sure it can be done with apt module.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use [conditionals](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html).

If you need more detailed/specific answer, then post a more detailed/specific question.